# Add save callback to a single ActiveRecord instance, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to add a callback to a single ActiveRecord instance? As a further constraint this is to go on a library so I don't have control over the class (except to monkey-patch it).

This is more or less what I want to do:

```
def do_something_creazy
  message = Message.new
  message.on_save_call :do_even_more_crazy_stuff
end

def do_even_more_crazy_stuff(message)
  puts "Message #{message} has been saved! Hallelujah!"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like that by adding a callback to the object right after creating it and like you said, monkey-patching the default AR `before_save` method:

```
def do_something_ballsy
    msg = Message.new
    def msg.before_save(msg)
        puts "Message #{msg} is saved."
        # Calls before_save defined in the model
        super
    end
end
```

Comment: What about if there's already a before_save? Should I somehow save it and call it from my own before_save?

Comment: Edited my post for this one. Check it out.

Comment: Instead of defining the method on the objects metaclass, extend the object with a module. See my answer below. This allows you to 'stack' callbacks, by extending the object with multiple modules.

Answer (score 3):

For something like this you can always define your own crazy handlers:

```
class Something < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :run_before_save_callbacks

  def before_save(&block)
    @before_save_callbacks ||= [ ]
    @before_save_callbacks << block
  end

protected
  def run_before_save_callbacks
    return unless @before_save_callbacks

    @before_save_callbacks.each do |callback|
      callback.call
    end
  end
end
```

This could be made more generic, or an ActiveRecord::Base extension, whatever suits your problem scope. Using it should be easy:

```
something = Something.new

something.before_save do
  Rails.logger.warn("I'm saving!")
end
```

Comment: Note that he doesn't access to change the class directly.

Comment: He did say "except to monkey patch it" which is precisely what this does if you apply it to ActiveRecord::Base directly.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use this approach in my own project to be able to inject additional actions into the 'save' action of a model from my controller layer. I took Tadman's answer a stage further and created a module that can be injected into active model classes:

```
module InstanceCallbacks 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  CALLBACKS = [:before_validation, :after_validation, :before_save, :before_create, :after_create, :after_save, :after_commit]

  included do
    CALLBACKS.each do |callback|
      class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__
        #{callback} :run_#{callback}_instance_callbacks

        def run_#{callback}_instance_callbacks
          return unless @instance_#{callback}_callbacks
          @instance_#{callback}_callbacks.each do |callback|
            callback.call
          end
        end

        def #{callback}(&callback)
          @instance_#{callback}_callbacks ||= []
          @instance_#{callback}_callbacks << callback
        end
      RUBY
    end
  end
end
```

This allows you to inject a full set of instance callbacks into any model just by including the module. In this case:

```
class Message
  include InstanceCallbacks
end
```

And then you can do things like:

```
m = Message.new
m.after_save do
  puts "In after_save callback"
end
m.save!
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to bobthabuilda's answer - instead of defining the method on the objects metaclass, extend the object with a module:

```
def do_something_ballsy
  callback = Module.new do   
    def before_save(msg)
      puts "Message #{msg} is saved."
      # Calls before_save defined in the model
      super
    end
  end
  msg = Message.new
  msg.extend(callback)
end
```

This way, you can define multiple callbacks, and they will be executed in the opposite order you added them.

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow you to use an ordinary `before_save` construction, i.e. calling it on the class, only in this case, you call it on the instance's metaclass so that no other instances of `Message` shall be affected. (Tested in Ruby 1.9, Rails 3.13)

```
msg = Message.new
class << msg
  before_save -> { puts "Message #{self} is saved" } # Here, `self` is the msg instance
end
Message.before_save # Calling this with no args will ensure that it gets added to the callbacks chain (but only for your instance)
```

Test it thus:

```
msg.save         # will run the before_save callback above
Message.new.save # will NOT run the before_save callback above
```

Comment: Problem is that after you do this, when you load and attempt to save the next model of the same class, you get an error like this: `NoMethodError: undefined method '_callback_after_7872' for #<Message:0x0000000ff71980>`